# How to make screen reader read different content from the content within the span

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

If I have the following span in the html,

```
<span>10:45</span>
```

Is there a way to let screen reader reads "Document value at 10:45"? 
At first I thought I could use `aria-label="Document value at 10:45"` but it does not seem to work. Also, I feel like aria-label is not supposed to be used in this way. Dose anyone know if there is any other aria related attribute that can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The `aria-label` is only useful for interactive elements

Currently you have to use something like :

```
 <span class="sr-only">Document value at 10:45</span>
 <span aria-hidden="true">10:45</span>
```

Or the following

```
 <span class="sr-only">Document value at </span>10:45
```

With `sr-only` being a css class you have to design to be visible only by screenreaders (like the one in bootstrap).